# C# HTTP Post code not getting expected response

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have a sample htm file with following structure and it POSTs the xml and gets the response xml. I need to do the same with C#. See my C# code below the html.

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td width=10%>&nbsp;</td><td><h2>API Test Form</h2></td></tr>
<tr><td width=10%>&nbsp;</td><td><h3>Command: get_Details </h3></td></tr>

<form action="https://test.test.com/getDetails" method=POST>


<tr>
<td width=10%>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<textarea name="xml" rows=15 cols=80>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>   
    <test1>xcvb</test1>     
</Request>

</textarea>
</td>

</tr>
<tr><td width=10%>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td width=10%>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit Request"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>



private static string MSDNHttpPost1()
{
    // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://test.test.com/getDetails");
    // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
    request.Method = "POST";

    // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.    

    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"C:\request.xml");
    string postData = doc.InnerXml;

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);


    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    //request.ContentType = "text/xml";

    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    //request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    // Get the request stream.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    // Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    // Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close();
    // Get the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    // Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Display the content.
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
    // Clean up the streams.
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();

    return responseFromServer;

}
```

The C# code was adapted from MSDN site. But the response shows me a message with a error which basically says the server could not read the xml file. I have been suggested to include "data="before the xml while posting. But that makes no difference on the response.

Any clues as to what I am missing?.

Comment: please post the exception details - type & message.  also, ensure that the file c:\request.xml exists, and that the application pool identity has permission to read the file

Comment: @Jason  I don't have any exception messages. The response xml just indicates a processing error on server side for POSTed input. Have no issues reading the xml either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the html in the question, the request xml is housed within a TextArea control

```
<textarea name="xml" rows=15 cols=80>
```

I prefixed the request xml with "xml=" which did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The correct content-type when posting XML is:

```
application/xml
```

The text/xml content-type is obsolete, and also [seriously broken](http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/03/text-xml).

Comment: +1 as I think that this is the correct answer to the problem.

Comment: I changed the content-type, but still no effect on the response

Comment: Try setting content-type to "application/xml;charset=utf-8"

Comment: "application/xml;charset=utf-8"  didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest you use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or similar tool so that you can see exactly what is being send in the POST request of the form that you have when you execute it separately trough a web browser. Then instantiate the `HttpWebRequest` object and set all it's properties as per what you saw in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

When you loaded the XML document, I think you wanted:

```
string postData = doc.OuterXml;
```

Comment: InnerXml and OuterXml are the same for me in this case.